# How to use multi CPUs to make the computation faster in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, parallel-processing, mpi

I am wondering to speed up my computation in linux? As an example, I have the following script: example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
n1=1; n2=1000
while [ $n1 -le $n2 ]
do
cat << EOF > test.f 
       open (1,file='$n1.txt',form='formatted', status='unknown')
       write (1, *) "Hello World!"
       stop;end
EOF
gfortran test.f
./a.out
(( n1++ ))
done
```

If I execute the above example.sh, then it will execute 1000 times. My original fortran program is little big and takes ~3 minutes to exucute once. So it takes ~2 days to finish my script. So how can I use multi-CPUs to make this faster? My system shows CPU(s): 8.

Comment: You are writing a fortran program via a script, compiling this program, and then running it? This has got to be the worst possible way for you to do this. Put your loop and code all inside a fortran program that takes input parameter(s) and compile/run it once. Then we can talk about implementing MPI.

Comment: Thank you @NoseKnowsAll . Yes, my script writes a the fortran program, compiles and then runs. Because same fortran program will execute for many different text files. So do you mean I should write everything in fortran code?

Comment: Yes. At the least, write a fortran program that takes in a filename. Compile it once. Run your script loop that only changes the filename you're inputting to your program. You should only ever compile a program once.

Comment: The next step after that would be writing a fortran program that takes in a filename corresponding to an ASCII file containing all the filenames that you want to run on. Your loop would then be internal to the fortran program and you could theoretically implement that loop using MPI or OpenMP.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll The Unix way is to have programs process files as arguments, rather than reading a list of files. This allows "natural" use of the shell with globbing. And Fortran now has a proper way of reading arguments, so it's a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

[GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) does a great job.

GNU Parallel can be used for executing jobs in parallel using one or more computers. This takes away the need to manage processes and gives us a method to execute binaries in parallel.

So, your script (let us call this test.sh) becomes

```
#!/bin/bash
n1=$1
cat << EOF > test.f 
   open (1,file='$n1.txt',form='formatted', status='unknown')
   write (1, *) "Hello World!"
   stop;end
EOF
gfortran test.f
./a.out
```

You can now invoke the script test.sh using 'parallel' as shown below.

```
seq 1000 | parallel -j 8 --workdir $PWD ./test.sh {}
```

`-j 8` specifies the number of jobs to be run. This will launch `./test.sh 1, ./test.sh 2, ./test.sh 3 ... ./test.sh 1000` and ensures that 8 of them are running in parallel.

Comment: This seems a great method. I understood the whole process except the first line n1=$1. I know n1 is assigned with $1, but I don't know what does $1 mean. Will you be so kind to explain this. Thank you very much @Sidharth.N.Kashyap

Comment: $1 captures the first argument supplied in the command line.

example: ./test.sh abc

abc will be available to you in $1

Answer (score 2):

This code will execute itself eight times (each time in the background) and then waits for all eight of them to exit:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" = 0 ]; then

  trap 'kill -9 $job_list' 0  # clean up if given CTRL+C

  i=0; CPUs=8; total=1000
  while [ $i -lt $CPUs ]; do
    from=$((i*total/CPUs+1))
    i=$((i+1))
    to=$((i*total/CPUs))
    bash $0 $from $to &
    job_list="$job_list $!"
  done

  wait
  trap - 0  # done, remove cleanup code
  exit

fi

n1=$1; n2=$2
while [ $n1 -le $n2 ]; do
  cat << EOF > test$n1.f 
         open (1,file='$n1.txt',form='formatted', status='unknown')
         write (1, *) "Hello World!"
         stop;end
EOF
  trap "rm -f test$n1.f a$n1.out" 0
  gfortran test$n1.f -o a$n1.out
  ./a$n1.out
  rm test$n1.f a$n1.out
  (( n1++ ))
done
```

This runs eight loops of 125 runs of the given Fortran code.  All eight loops are run simultaneously.

This uses [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wait) and [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29): using `&` at the end of a command runs it as a background job (and keeps going without waiting for it to finish), `$!` is the job spec for the most recently backgrounded job (which we save in `$job_list` so we can kill it if needed), and `wait`, when given no arguments, will wait for *all* backgrounded jobs before continuing.

Comment: Thank you so much @Adam Katz. Before I start executing this script, may I confirm the follwoing. I am a user of the remote server. So whether it will affect any other's job, since we are using kill -9 command in the very begining.

Comment: I'm not a Fortran expert (nor do I know that you're going to run that specific code), but if it is expensive to run, you will be hammering all eight cores and others might not like it.  **The `kill` command is safe** because it only kills the processes we created and noted (see `$job_list`).  A `trap` only triggers when the program *exits*, and if it cleanly exits, this code removes the `trap` and will never kill anything.  The `kill` is really just for if you need to hit `^C`

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, it is worth your while to rewrite your program to accept a command line argument. I have extended the code in your example below:

```
runfile.f90

program runfile
  character(len=128) :: arg
  integer :: i

  do i = 1,command_argument_count()
     call get_command_argument(i, arg)

     open (1, file=trim(arg) // ".txt", form='formatted', status='unknown')
     write (1, *) "Hello world!"
  end do
end program runfile
```

You can then compile this program once (probably also with some more aggressive compile flags, if you're interested in speed) and parallelize with GNU parallel as mentioned in another answer:

```
seq -w 1000 | parallel -j 8 ./runfile {}
```

The way I've done the command-line processing is like many Unix tools, so even if you don't parallelize, you can now call your program like `./runfile {01..10}` to do 10 runs. Also, if the text files actually are things to be processed, you will be able to modify the program slightly to allow calls like `./runfile *.txt`.